# Create two axis stacked columns chart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

The data I'd like to chart is like this:

```
       2000       2001         2002
A        x          x           x
B        x          x           x
C        x          x           x
D        x          x           x
E        x          x           x
```

I'd like to have a chart where:

- the x-axis values are the years 2000-2002
- for each year there are 2 stacked columns of data:

  - the first column has the values from A and B stacked on top of each other
  - the second column has the values from C, D and E stacked on top of each other

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You're asking for a graph which includes both clustered and stacked data columns. I don't see any of this type of graph in Excel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always check Peltier's site for all my graphing needs. This should do it for you.
http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/ClusterStack.html

Comment: An updated tutorial can be found at http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/clustered-stacked-column-bar-charts/